# Laravel 5.0, 5.1, 5.2 changes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel. I have version 5.2 running on my local development machine and also deployed to shard hosting account. There is so much information available, but so many things have changed with 5.0, 5.1, and 5.2 (and I guess 5.3 soon, too).

Can anyone recommend the best place to go for a detailed list of the changes and differences between these versions? The release notes don't really seem to cover the detail that I need.

For example, I got bogged down by the fact that the `lists()` method used to return an array, but now it returns a collection so you have to do a `lists()->all()`. This is just one example of the things that have tripped me up as I'm building my first Laravel application. Thanks!

Comment: You should look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade - most breaking changes are documented here

Answer (score 1):

All changes in each Version are very well documented in the [Laravel Upgrade Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade).

Just make sure to read the Docs carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Laravel official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0) page and go to sub category you need to search. Then go with different versions. This will give you a clear idea.